# Is there a clean way to get android build specific information in flutter code?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm in the process of migrating my App built on Android using Java to using Flutter + Dart.

Like my current app, I am adding 2 build types - `release` and `debug` in the `build.gradle` file. I am specifying different Server API URLs to be used in these build Types.

Sample buildType information -

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        manifestPlaceholders = [hostName: "PROD SERVER", "version": "v1"]
    }
    debug {
        manifestPlaceholders = [hostName: "STAGE SERVER", "version": "v1"]
    }
}
```

**In native android, I was able to use `android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo` and `android.os.Bundle` to get the information in the code to dynamically use the base URLs.**

Sample code from my native app is as follows :

```
ApplicationInfo app = this.getPackageManager()
          .getApplicationInfo(this.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
Bundle bundle = app.metaData;
API_HOST = bundle.getString("api.host");
API_VERSION = bundle.getString("api.version");
```

- Is there a flutter + dart alternative to this?

I have been reading up and the way out seems to be by creating multiple Main files and then building the production/dev app by using the appropriate file.